# ii-ii6-I progression

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions, history

I've heard this progression many times and in many ways over the course of my life, but I can't seem to assign a name to it or find out any further information about it or its history. It goes as follows:

ii (3 times) - ii6 - ii - ii6 - I

I use it with Am, Am6 and G major and it seems to have a triumphal and/or conclusive nature to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? By the way, note that ii6 is V9 without a root.

Comment: This feels like kind of a relative of the ["Hollywood cadence"](https://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.13.19.4/mto.13.19.4.lehman.html).

Comment: ii6, meaning a triad ii6/3, is not the same as Am6, a minor triad with added M6. Makes a difference, because the later has a tritone, but, the former does not.

Answer (score 5):

Minor chords with inner movement within the harmony are very common in different styles of music. They may have a specific name or history, I can’t recall offhand. When a chord progression works it tends to get used by many different artists, possibly with variations, and sounds familiar to us.

The reason Am to Am6 to G has the triumphant and conclusive nature you described is very simple. Those 3 chords basically function in a very similar way to a ii-V7-I, a subdominant-dominant-tonic resolution. After the Am you have an Am6, which is basically a D7 with an E instead of a D in the chord (or a rootless D9/A). It also is the first inversion of F#m7b5, which is a viio chord, another dominant chord in G major. That chord has most of the defining elements you need for a V7-I resolution, which is the F#-C tritone resolving inward to the G-B root and third of the I chord. The only thing it lacks is the descending 5th movement from D-G in the bass.

Comment: Bonus points if you respell Am6 as F#m7b5/A (F# half-diminished 7th).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Although enharmonically equivalent, they're not functionally equivalent, and Am6 better expressing the chord's function as "minor with inner movement".

Comment: @Dekkadeci I did not respell it but it does merit mentioning, which I did in paragraph 2.

Comment: @John Belzaguy Thanks for your response. The information on the theory behind the progression is interesting. I'm recently retired and have taken up learning the guitar and theory as a hobby, so I know (at this early point) about the major 6th substitution for the relative minor 7th. I was not aware it also worked for the minor 6th too.

The phrase I'm thinking of is so common and used so often that I'm almost certain it has a name. It is very similar (but not exact) to the theme played by the organ in the first three seconds of this song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp8yKwPrzwM

Comment: @EdwardKirby My pleasure. The example in the link very different though, it is a I to a iv6 back to I, in this case, Db-Gbm6-Db. Often progressions don’t actually have names but are sometimes named for the song they are identified with, “I Got Rhythm” changes, “Lollipop” turnaround for I-vi-V-V, etc.

Comment: @Andy Bonner That seems to be the right track (Golden Age of Hollywood movies). In more recent years (or decades?), I have occasionally heard this motif used ironically in comedy sketches or movies to trumpet some grand announcement that turns out to be nothing. But it sounds as if comes from the early half of the 20th century, and it does seem to have an MGM feel to it. And it's used so frequently, I figured it had a name.

This is not a big deal -- I was just curious -- so no need to waste anyone's time. Thanks everyone for your consideration.